# Teradata Error 5407 Invalid operation for DateTime or Interval

Tags: sql, database, teradata, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

I am trying to an `Ins` from a `bigint` col to a `bigint` col and I get this error

```
Error 5407 Invalid operation for DateTime or Interval.
```

here is the query pattern

```
    INSERT  INTO sanboxdb.Mtb     (  colA < offending column is BIGINT > ,
        <other non offensive col-list> ) 

SELECT    
( TRIM(Ptb.Colx) ||
TRIM(Coly)||
TRIM(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Xtb.ColZ   
ORDER   BY ColP,ColQ  )  +

COALESCE(SUBSTR(CAST(Mtb.ColA_BigIntCol   AS CHAR (20)),
        6),0) )  ) ( BIGINT)   AS colA  /* , TYPE  ( colA ). I verified that type is indeed BIGINT */,  


        <rest of the query Logic here.All the rest of the col checkout fine>'
```

I can do this

```
`Ins into ( BigintCol) sel '1123343434'` <br>
```

and it wont complain !

But If I do this

```
ins into DB.TB  ( Bigintcol ) sel  substring ( bigintcol,6,0) from DB.TB sample 5
```

or in fact this

```
 ins into DB.TB  ( Bigintcol ) sel  substring ( bigintcol,6,0) ( bigint) from DB.TB sample 5
```

It does not like this . You can ignore this component

```
( TRIM(Ptb.Colx) ||
TRIM(Coly)||
TRIM(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Xtb.ColZ   
ORDER   BY ColP,ColQ  )  +
```

I included it just to  show the actual query outline but the offensive component is this part

```
  COALESCE(SUBSTR(CAST(Mtb.ColA_BigIntCol   AS CHAR (20)),
            6),0) )  )
```

None of these `datatypes` are `Interval` or `datetime`. In fact it's the same `bigint datatype`. Why then does it throw the error like that .

Comment: Can you show the DDL of the target and source tables? Btw, if the source column is a BIGINT you better avoid casting to string and back by using `ColA_BigIntCol MOD 10000000000000000`.

Comment: Hi Dieter TY VM . Actually as  I found out , it was not the `bigint` col throwing the error. The select  had  a `derived` col. that was inserted into a `timestamp` column . Source col was an implicit integer ( sel created col. that was int )  and target was a `TS`. `Int_col ( varchar (20) ) ( timestamp (6) )  ` did the fix. What got me focused on the `biginto` col & ignore the others , Dieter , was the fact that  if I changed the `Bigint` col value to a fixed val, `insert` would run fine. But  the `datetime /interval` didnt relate to `Bigint`.

Comment: though  I still cant follow how the very same insert would run fine if I substitute the `bigint` with a fixed value and run the `SQL` without the fix.TY again <br>  WIsh you all  a very Merry X Mas.

Comment: Teradata performs automatic typecasts in *some* cases, but not for INT->Timestamp :-)  For more details see http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_151K/IMPLICIT_TYPE_CONVERSIONS.html

Answer (score 1):

I faced no issue when I simulate scenario like you, is it possible for you to give sample values for bigintcol? or try to construct similar scenario like me and debug.

```
/* create table with bigint column */
create table test3
( a bigint)
primary index(a);

/* inserted bigint value */
insert into test3 values(9223372036854775807);

/* selected bigint as character and operation you want to perform */
select cast(a as char(19)),  COALESCE(SUBSTR(CAST(a   AS CHAR (20)),6),0) bi
from test3;

/* inserted char value in bigint column*/
insert into test3
select  COALESCE(SUBSTR(CAST(a   AS CHAR (20)),6),0) bi
from test3;
```

Comment: Hi Bhavesh TY VM for response.  I messed up - the problem was not `bigint` col but another col , not being cast . I replied with details to Dieters comment.